# PGAdmin to CSV error

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I tried to export PGAdmin table (Students) to csv using the following query:

```
Copy (Select * From public."Students") To '/Users/dar/Desktop/postgs2sqlserver.csv' With CSV;
```

and I got the following error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "/Users/dar/Desktop/postgs2sqlserver.csv" for writing: Permission denied SQL state: 42501
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a "copy", the file is created with the perms of the user
running the PostgreSQL process, `postgres`.

You can change that file's perms to allow the user to
write to it, or choose a directory that the server user already has
rights to.

You may try like this in Linux to change the file owner:-

```
chown user file
chown user directory
chown -R user directory
```

to give write permisions:-

```
chmod a+w file
chmod -R a+w directory
```

Comment: 1.How can I change the file's permissions to allow user to write? 2. How do I choose a directory that the server has rights to?

Comment: I also tried a different table "weather" with a different command and it still failed:                    \copy (SELECT * from weather) To '/Users/dar/Desktop/postgs2sqlserv.csv' With CSV;

Comment: the error I get with \copy is the following:    Permission denied